# Find Optimal Path in N-Dimensions Subject to Maximization/Minimization Constraints

Tags: geometry, optimization

I know this deals with the development of an app, but due to the mathematical underpinnings I feel this is the best place to post the question.

I'm currently developing an AI film app that, while functional, can be optimized.

Here's the deal. Part of the app outputs points in n-dimensional space (not the end product, but important to its generation). They follow (roughly) a normal distribution centered around the origin. I need to find the optimal path through the hypercube containing all of these points, subject to the following constraints:

0) The path must start/end at maximally distant points within the hypercube. This cannot be compromised.

1) The path must maximize the volume/area/length of space visited.

2) The path must minimize adjacencies of temporally distant path points.

In 1 dimension, the only solution is a straight line between start and end points. (I think.)

I.e., in two dimensions, a spiral would satisfy 1 but fail 2, as spirals fill space fairly well, but for a given point on the spiral, that point is very close to points not adjacent to it on the path (i.e. 'temporally distant,' if you imagine yourself traveling along the path over time). A spiral would also fail 0 (think about it). Conversely, a straight line across the plane would satisfy 0 and 2 but fail 1, as path points are minimally atemporally-adjacent but visit minimal space.

I would imagine a fairly good solution in 2 dimensions would be a loose S-curve between the start and end points of the path. But I have no idea what the solutions would be in higher dimensions. Furthermore I'm fairly confident that the optimal solution for 1 will always fail 2, and vice verse - therefore, the problem is finding the happy medium between constraints.

I'm trying to use a genetic algorithm to generate 'good-enough' solutions, but I'm looking for someone to help me find the truly optimal, mathematically provable optimal path for a given set of dimensions.

Comment: Sounds like a graph-theoretic approach would fit. Where you'd have a complete graph with edge weights representing distances between points. Also, would there not be a tradeoff between 0) and 1)?

Comment: @kbau - yes, but 0 is absolutely required while 1 and 2 are opposing optimization goals. I'll edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: are you allowed to revisit points?

Comment: You aren't visiting points; rather, traversing the hypercube occupied BY the points. The path should be a continuous curve.

Comment: Ah, ok, some more questions then. How do you define volume or area if you're travelling along a curve? Do you just mean the length of your path? I would start with seeing if given a curve ${\bf x}(t)$ you're able to write down the constraints. 2) seems particularly tricky. because there are infinitely many point pairs (between which to measure distance) on a continuous curve. Do your normally distributed points serve any other purpose than defining the hypercube? And then how do you pick the hypercube (many options if less than $n$ points on the boundary).

Comment: There are many [space-filling curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve) that fulfill the stated rules. If the intent is to cover all the points instead, then this could be considered a variant of the [travelling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), so some graph-theoretic approach would likely work in finding a *near-optimal* solution with acceptable time/space complexity.

Comment: I'll answer in order. First, for volume, there are several ways, but the way I've been thinking about it, divide the cube up into smaller cubes and count the number of cubes entered by the path.

Comment: @kbau second, divide the path up into equally spaced points with a position stamp and a time stamp. Create a cost function that multiplies point to point distance by some other function penalizing large differences in time stamp.

Comment: @kbau for the hypercube, find the max/min point positions along each axis and set those for the hypercube/rectangle's vertices.